# instantaneous travel

Tags: power, passive-networks, steady-state

Problem 9.7 of Basic Engineering Circuit Analysis asks one to "Find the instantaneous travel supplied by the source [...]"

The word "travel" does not appear anywhere else in chapter 9. I suspect it is just a typo, and was meant to be "power" as the other questions ask about power. Chapter 9 is titled "Steady-State Power Analysis." Should it be "power," instead of "travel"?

Is "travel" even a concept? If it is, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the field of lumped circuit network analysis, the word "travel" has no meaning. Considering that the first 28 problems for Chapter 9 ask for you to determine power, it is safe to assume that problem 7 is also asking for power.